# SQL Server : Distinct + random rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

How do I pick distinct as well as random rows from a SQL Server 2008/2005 table?

I have a list of tips from which I need to pick a few tips **randomly** and they must be **unique** too.

I tried:

```
Select 
    Distinct Tips 
From 
    jfpastrologytips 
Where 
    GetDate() <= validtill 
Order by 
    NewId()
```

and got commissioned with exception

> *Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get around this by using `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`

```
Select Tips 
From jfpastrologytips 
Where GetDate() <= validtill 
GROUP BY Tips 
Order by NewId()
```

Comment: I would also add a `TOP N` to this... you say you only want a few rows, then only select a few rows.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, you don't need distinct if you are only selecting one of them:

```
Select top 1 Tips 
From jfpastrologytips 
Where GetDate() <= validtill 
Order by NewId()
```

Comment: I don't see only one mentioned in the question?

Comment: Here I can select multiple tips, I am afraid top(1) will allow me to pick only one row..

Comment: It is true now that I look, it was the title that got me -- row was singular.

Comment: @AmitRanjan - use Martin's answer then.